# How do I re-associate HTTP links with my browser in OS X?

Tags: macos, iterm, web-browser, url

I installed [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) the other day, and was playing around with it. In the process I seemed to have messed up the handling of HTTP hyperlinks on my system. Sometimes (annoyingly, not every time, which is *very* confusing - I can't spot a pattern) when I click an HTTP link in the Twitter app, MS Word, and so on, it opens a new iTerm2 terminal window or tab, and the webpage doesn't open. How can I get back to the original behavior and have the link open in the default web browser?

I've already checked the iTerm2 preferences - under "URL schemes", no scheme is selected:

[image]

Comment: Try to reassign the URL schemes using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/).

Comment: If there is an entry for it in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`, try deleting it and restarting.

Comment: Lauri, your answer worked. https (not http) was associated with iTerm2, not Safari - hence the "random" behavior. I've fixed that now. If you change your comment to an answer, I can mark it.

Comment: Andrew, could you copypaste the solution to an answer and mark the question as solve, please? I'd rather not steal Lauri's reputation but it's preferable you get it than I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file associations for both HTTP & HTTPS, make sure both are set to Safari.

A simple way to do this would be using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)

[image]

<sub>Answered as Community Wiki just so we don't have a dangling question when there's a perfectly good answer in the comments.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Set Safari to be your default web browser.

Comment: How do you do that?